# Iterating JSON data repeating itself 3 times

Tags: python, json

I'm not sure why this repeats it self 3 times.
The code blow prints 888888888 3 times.
i would like it only to print the once

The reason i'm using this method, there will be multiple type, id's and attributes which i will work with.

```
jsondata = { "data": [
        {
            "type": "product",
            "id": "888888888",
            "attributes": {
                "ean": "888888888",
                "name": "product name",
                }
        }
        ]
        }

jsonObject = jsondata
for inner_dict in jsonObject["data"]:
  for key,value in inner_dict.items():
      test = inner_dict["attributes"]["ean"]
      print (test)
```

Comment: Lose the `for key,value in inner_dict.items():` loop. You don't use either key or value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through the dict unnecessarily.

loosing the second loop should do the trick

```
jsondata = { 
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "product",
            "id": "888888888",
            "attributes": {
                "ean": "888888888",
                "name": "product name",
                }
        }
      ]
    }

jsonObject = jsondata
for inner_dict in jsonObject["data"]:
  test = inner_dict["attributes"]["ean"]
  # for key,value in inner_dict.items():
  #   print(key, value)
    
  print (test)
```